# QML: Only One Row visible TableView with Row and Item Delegates

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In the following code:

```
Rectangle{
    width: { parent==null ? 640: parent.width }
    height: { parent==null ? 480: parent.height }

    Image {
        id: mainBackground
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "qrc:///wallDiscoveryBackground"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        TableView {
            id: wallDiscoveryTable
            anchors.margins: parent.width * 0.6
            width: parent.width

            clip: true

            model: discoveredWallsTableModel

            TableViewColumn { role: "name"; width: 240; title: "Name" }
            TableViewColumn { role: "ipAddress"; width: 240; title: "IP Address" }
            TableViewColumn { role: "status"; width: 240; title: "Status" }

            rowDelegate: wallDiscoveryRowDelegate    //comment out
            itemDelegate: wallDiscoveryItemDelegate  //comment out
        }

        Component {
            id: wallDiscoveryRowDelegate
            Rectangle {
                width: wallDiscoveryTable.width
                height: 640
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: wallDiscoveryItemDelegate
            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: styleData.textColor
                text: styleData.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out lines setting the row and item delegates (lines I have marked with "//comment out") then the table renders fine, indicative of the fact that the model I have specified is right. However, when I set the row and item delegates, I only get the first row of the table rendered.

Can someone point me to what is wrong in the second case (with row and item delegates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate is huge. 640 pixels is more than half the height of most screens. Your code doesn't run properly since the model doesn't exist, but if I use a dummy model and reduce the height to 100 pixels, I see other items. Also, you should be able to scroll down to see the other items, even with your current code.